# Python long polling server (same as existing PHP server)

Tags: php, python, server

I have a simple php script (that runs on xampp) for long polling server, but I would like to translate it to Python and make it a Python server. I'm kind off inexperienced with python (specially when it comes to web servers) and I haven't found any simple solutions for Python web servers that would do this same thing so I'm wondering, could anyone help me translating this script from php to Python.

My php script does this: it GETs timestamp from the client and then keeps comparing it to current modification time of file, and if they are different, it sends contents of file and new timestamp coded in JSON.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
$filename = dirname(__FILE__).'/data.txt';

$lastmodif = isset($_GET['timestamp']) ? $_GET['timestamp'] : 0;
$currentmodif = filemtime($filename);

while ($currentmodif <= $lastmodif){
    usleep(10000);
    clearstatcache();
    $currentmodif = filemtime($filename);
}

$response = array();
$response['msg'] = file_get_contents($filename);
$response['timestamp'] = $currentmodif;
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: that is a very broad question! there are so many ways you can run a python web server/web service/application server/... until you decide how you want to use python as server you are unlikely to get an answer...

Comment: As I have written in the question, I need it to do the same thing as my PHP script which is: when it gets a timestamp through GET, then it should run the checks on certain file's modification time, if that file's modification time is different than timestamp that we got from GET, then send a response. So, if someone could just show me an example of simple python server that would also be very useful.

Comment: @TomSilverhill - did I answer your request for "simple python server"?

Comment: @Yaron - I still didn't have enough time to try it out, but I will very soon. Then I'll let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following links include a sample of simple python server, and some additional information, it should give you a good starting point for python tcp/ip client/server programming:

**TCP/IP Client and Server** - https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html

**python wiki - TCP Communication** - https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication

**Python docs - 20.17.4.1. SocketServer.TCPServer Example** - https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#SocketServer.TCPServer